# Mapping an array of objects to dynamic array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and I would like to get an array of arrays of the combination shown here [x,y,value]. The limit of y will be 500 and then x would increment by 1 and y should start from 0 again.

```
Example: [0,0, 112] [0,1,75]...[0,500,42]
         [1,0,54] [1,1,98]...[1,500,67]
```

So the total number of arrays within the main arrays should be equal to the length of the array of objects.

```
[{
    color: "red",
    value: "112"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "75"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "19"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "20"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "47"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "68"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "75"
  }
]
```

This is just a sample data but my data is dynamic which can cross 3000+ values.

Format for the array of arrays is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXLaaa).

Please advice.

Comment: where do you get the colors from?

Comment: Colors is just an example. All i care is the values in the array

Comment: I really didn't understand the problem. Can you reformulate ?

Comment: i don't understand the problem. is it to generate from the arrays an array of objects? maybe it would help if you add the wanted format to the question and the wanted result.

Comment: So you want to take `[{..., value: "##"}, ...]` and convert that to `[[0, 0, ##], [0, 1,##]]` up to `[0, 500, ##]`, and then wrap back around to `[1, 0, ##]` if the object array contains more than 501 elements?

Comment: Yeah, so get the value from array of objects as the last element of array of arrays.. the first two indexes would be the x and y values. So it ranges from [0,0,value] [0,1,value]...[0,500,value]. So from 501st value, it will be [1,0,value] [1,1,value] and so on

Comment: @AndresSalgado you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic implementation. Basically loop over the contents of the array and then test if its mod 500 = 0 and if so then increment your counter. Notice i have the counter starting at -1 thats because the first iteration when i = 0 the `i % 500 == 0` evaluates to true.

```js
var sampleData = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "112"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "75"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "19"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "20"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "47"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "68"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "75"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "75"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "19"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "20"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "47"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "68"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "75"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "75"
  }
];

var result = [];
var outterIndex = -1;
var innerIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
  if (i % 500 == 0) {
    outterIndex++;
    innerIndex = -1;
  }
  innerIndex++;
  result.push([outterIndex, innerIndex, sampleData[i].value])
}


console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is really good. Thanks. But after reaching 500, it should again default back to 0. But here it goes like [1,500, value] and instead it should be [1,0,value]

Comment: Should be pretty simple to implement that change.

Comment: Can you help me with that please?

Comment: @a2441918 lol ok, i'll update it but make sure you review my change to see and understand why it was made so you can improve your skill set. Also if it solves your problem don't forget to mark it as the answer. Give me a minute ill update the answer.

Comment: Sure Adam. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @a2441918 Well thanks for marking this as the accepted answer, I don't feel dirty or used at all /s

Comment: Sorry @adam. I forgot to do that.